# How to iterate through one type of objects in arraylist?

Tags: java

I have some inheritance tree, and all its subclasses saved in an array list. So if classes `a, b, c` inherit from the `Foo` class, I have something like this:

```
private List<Foo> arr = new ArrayList<Foo>();

arr.add(new a());
arr.add(new a());
arr.add(new b());
arr.add(new c());
```

I want to iterate only through the a class objects from this array list. I can do it this way:

```
for(int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
   if(arr[i] instanceof a) {
      // ...
   }
}
```

And well, that should work, but I'd have to write this code in a couple of places...and there would be a couple of other if's inside the for loop, so the code would loose a lot of readability.

I was wondering, is there a shorter way to do this? Maybe just with the for loop?

Comment: Without knowing more then yes, this is how it's done. But if you give a concrete example, we might be able to tell if polymorphism is more suited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, you're right. This:

```
for(int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
    if(arr[i] instanceof a) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Is the best way to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You could write an own list, extending from ArrayList and overwrite the methods inherited from `Iterable`, and only show the next element if it's an instance of `a`.
Then your loop would look like this:

```
for(a obj : arr) {
    ...
}
```